# Having trouble getting Rails app to run on POW after rvm update upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3-p392

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rvm, rack-pow

I have a feeling this has to do with rvm no longer using an `.rvmrc` file:

```
SystemExit: exit
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.26/lib/bundler/setup.rb:16:in `exit'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.26/lib/bundler/setup.rb:16
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_requir e.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
```

Now `rvm` uses two files instead of `.rvmrc`:

```
.ruby-version
.ruby-gemset
```

I don't know that Pow knows how to use those files. Because those files above that are getting used are from the global gemset, which tells me that my gemset isn't getting picked up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use .rvmrc if you like, it will take precedence over the two new rvm .dotfiles.